# backup for installed Windows XP and operating application on new machine without requesting for a registry key to start applications

Tags: backup

I have an old XP operating system that works to function asphalt plant, I need to back up the plant operating system on a new machine but I don't have the Registry key anymore and the manufacturer company not exist, I made an image for the current operating system but when starting a popup window requiring Registry key shows up.
how can I do the backup with a fully functioning installed asphalt plant operating system on a new machine?

Comment: Do you mean _registration_ key? _Registry_ is a very specific term, it's a Windows component.

Comment: You cannot expect an image of XP to work on a new motherboard. What you want to do is near impossible.

Comment: Do you have more information about the asphalt software, such as it's name? Could you include a screenshot of the error? Also, how are you using the image you created? Are you running in a VM or cloning to a new machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is technically piracy even if the original software manufacturer is gone, so no one on this site will tell you how to do this (because it's against StackExchange's terms of use). I recommend you convince your bosses to either:

1. Buy new software that does something similar, or
2. Hire programmers to recreate the original software (which they can then resell to make back the expenses).

Either way, you'll want to move away from that XP setup ASAP. XP security updates ended nearly a decade ago. All you need is one ransomware virus to make your life miserable.

Comment: Why do you think it's piracy?

Comment: @gronostaj Copying software from one machine to another means your hardware ID changes. Some vendors require buying a new license for each new hardware ID (i.e. the license is locked to the original machine). The OP is asking how one bypasses the registration process to force the software to work without purchasing a new license from the vendor. Bypassing a licensing mechanism is piracy. The fact that the software complains despite the whole OS having been cloned indicates this may be the vendor's reasoning.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes software is licensed per machine, but the license could've been transferable. We don't know. According to OP's description they are essentially trying to virtualize a physical system and decommission the original hardware. That could be well within what the license allows. I think jumping to conclusions about this being piracy is premature. We don't have enough information.

Comment: @gronostaj Good point. I've added a comment asking the OP some questions that may help understand the situation better. I'll edit my answer once if we can get more relevant information.